# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class xyz from class zxy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails application, which runs fine if I launch it for development via

```
grails run-app
```

At an earlier stage I already had deployed that app to a tomcat instance on a node and didn’t encounter any issues. However, yesterday I was starting to get everything ready for production and was setting up a vagrant box to deploy the whole stack. And there suddenly has been something quite strange happening:

I have a method

```
def checkEmail(String email)
```

in my RegisterController, which calls a static method

```
static String normalize(final String email) throws InvalidEmailAddressException
```

within a groovy class which is placed under '/src/groovy' in the appropriate package in my project.

Whenever the checkEmail method in the controller gets called, I see the following exception:

```
2014-04-07 20:19:20,588 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalAccessError occurred when processing request: [GET] /register/checkEmail
tried to access class com.getgrape.core.exception.InvalidEmailAddressException from class com.getgrape.authority.RegisterController. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [checkEmail] of controller [com.getgrape.authority.RegisterController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.getgrape.core.exception.InvalidEmailAddressException from class com.getgrape.authority.RegisterController
    at com.getgrape.authority.RegisterController.checkEmail(RegisterController.groovy:128)
    ... 6 more
```

InvalidEmailAddressException looks like this and is placed under '/src/java' in the appropriate package in my project:

```
package com.getgrape.core.exception;

class InvalidEmailAddressException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    InvalidEmailAddressException() {
        super();
    }

    InvalidEmailAddressException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I basically don’t have any idea what is going on.

- I checked for a possible duplicate definition of
  InvalidEmailAddressException, but couldn’t find anything.
- I tried to rename the Exception in case I overlooked anything or this might conflict with another library, but that didn’t help
  either.
- I checked all the import statements and they look good as well.
- If I remove the call to the normalize method entirely, the error goes away. So, that must be something about that method, which throws the
  exception.
- I tried to remove the static modifier from the method and call it via an instantiated object, but that didn't make a difference.
- I checked the war file, to see if it contains the InvalidEmailAddressException and it is where it should be.
- I tried to deploy that application to a freshly downloaded tomcat, but the issue persists. So, it shouldn't be a configuration
  problem.
- There are no compiler errors.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

```
java version is: oracle jdk 1.7.0_51
grails: 2.3.7
running on ubuntu 12.04
```

the war is build via "grails war” and I always have been running “grails clean-all” before building the war.

Comment: Package name should be all lower case like. `com.getgrape.core.exception.InvalidEmailAddressException`. This is a naming convention.

Comment: Sorry, just a minor error when creating that question. Package names are all lower case, but that shouldn't affect the issue anyway. Corrected the question now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without the `public` modifier, the method is only available to the package the classes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. This applies to your exception class which is not public. The constructors and methods should also be public if you want global access.

Comment: Well, that's immensely embarrassing. I've been working with package visibility quite a few times within JPA projects. I should buy you a beer... Any idea why that would not show up in dev mode? I vaguely remember that I had read somewhere about a bug within java, but that's pretty vague memory and I can't find anything about that, so that might be nonsense as well....

Comment: @codeySmurf I have no idea what Grails or Groovy are. At first, I thought it was a ClassLoader error, but I actually then read the rest of the post and saw that the default for the `normalize` method and had to answer then and there. I read further and saw the exception class and that was it.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Usually that at least would lead to a compiler error, when not using anything dynamic like groovy.